# adding listeners to buttons to execute functions

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch on different buttons (different ids) that upon click, perform the same logic. This is why I added listeners to each of them so upon `click`, the `clearOrSelectAll` function is executed with the appropriate `clearSelectArr[i]` as input.

Currently I am getting this as my error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

All the buttons have a `class="clearSelect"`

My code:

```
var clearSelectArr = [  "selectAllXP", "selectAll7", "selectAll8",
                        "selectAll8_1", "selectAll10_6", "selectAll10_8", 
                        "selectAll10_9", "selectAllios", "selectAll4_4", 
                        "selectAll4_3", "selectAll4_2", "selectAll4_1", 
                        "selectAll4_0", "clearAllXP", "clearAll7", 
                        "clearAll8", "clearAll8_1", "clearAll10_6", 
                        "clearAll10_8", "clearAll10_9", "clearAllios",
                        "clearAll4_4", "clearAll4_3", "clearAll4_2", 
                        "clearAll4_1", "clearAll4_0"];

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("clearSelect");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.addEventListeners("click", clearOrSelectAll(button.id));
}
```

Each button has an id associated with it. These ids are the same as the one in the `clearSelectArr`. I want to be able to add the listener function with the same id as the button.

Comment: The method is called `addEventListener`, not `addEventListeners`.

Comment: Felix probably solved your problem, but on a side note: `clearSelectArr[clearSelectArr.indexOf(button.id)])` is the same as `button.id`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `addEventListener`, not `addEventListeners` (note the `s`).

Whenever you have `foo(bar())`, `bar` is called first and its return value is passed to `foo`. So in your case, you are calling `clearOrSelectAll` first and pass the return value to `addEventListener`.

However, `addEventListener` expects a function as argument and if `clearOrSelectAll` doesn't return a function, this won't work.

Do

```
button.addEventListener("click", clearOrSelectAll);
```

and access the element the handler is bound to via `this`.